# Difference between sourceforge SPNEGO vs WAFFLE

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, spnego, waffle

Can someone clarify to me the difference between http://spnego.sourceforge.net/ vs https://dblock.github.io/waffle/README.html?

I know that the SPNEGO in sourceforge is a small servlet filter that implements the SPNEGO mechanism, but requires server side config (i.e registering service principal name, creating service account etc..).

And for WAFFLE, according to its description, "Unlike many other implementations Waffle on Windows does not require any server-side Kerberos keytab setup, it’s a drop-in solution". what does this mean?

Currently, I'm using SPNEGO to implement SSO on our grails application, but I'm a little bit concerned of the several LDAP/Kerberos configurations we need to implement to our customer's environment upon delivery.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

WAFFLE only runs on Windows machine. So AD integration is given. SpNegoHttpFilter can run anywhere.